# Is there any way to access the Google Cardboard magnet switch on iOS without Unity?

Tags: ios, google-cardboard

On Android, we have a nice Google Cardboard SDK with headtracking and access to the magnet switch for the people who don't want to deal with unity.

Is there any way to access just the magnet switch on iOS? I don't need any headtracking or other cardboard features - just the magnet.